# NumPy: Need help taking average of a histogram

Tags: python, numpy, average

I am currently working on an image detection project and a certain block of code requires to capture the last frame of our video output. In order to obtain the best results we must create a histogram that plots the allocations of all the pixels (which I have done already) and average them out in order to obtain the ambient light levels. Currently my code looks like this:

```
from PIL import Image
import os
from pylab import *
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import ImageDraw


#read image 
image1 = array(Image.open("EE_Design_Chimys.jpg").convert('L'))

#plot image
imshow(image1)
#create a new figure
figure()
#dont use colors
gray()
#show contours with origin upper left corner
contour(image1, origin='image')
axis('equal')
axis('off')
figure()
a = hist(image1.flatten(),128)

#attempt to average out histogram
average(a)

show(a)
```

And when I run this code it outputs an error message like so:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Perez/Desktop/Python Stuff/mod_amb_light.py", line 25, in <module>
     average(a)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 935, in average
    avg = a.mean(axis)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 65, in _mean
    ret = umr_sum(arr, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (128,) (129,)
```

I am not to sure as to what exactly this means how to even begin to solve it. If anyone has any useful hints or ideas please share your knowledge! Thank you.

Regards,
Jaime Perez Jr.

Comment: Please show the *full* traceback in your question, not just the last line. It's not obvious where in your code that error is occurring.

Comment: `a = hist(image1.flatten(),128)` looks incorrect - `plt.hist` returns three arguments, only the first of which contains the histogram bin counts. At the moment `a` is a tuple of `(bin_counts, bin_edges, patches)`, and you're trying to pass the whole thing to `np.average`.

Comment: @ali_m I updated my traceback! Also, I thought 'plt.hist' returned two arguments; '(array, bin_edges)'? Also, I'm not to familiar with the '.flatten()' function either. I'm rather new to python and all these DIP techniques are overwhelming at times.

Comment: It sounds as though you're confusing [`np.histogram`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) with [`plt.hist`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist). These are all well-documented - to see the docstrings, use `help(<function_name>)` in your Python interpreter (or just `<function_name>?` if you're using IPython).